# Mongo Query with distinct + Like

Tags: mongodb

Trying to get unique userNames for a specified time stamp (ts field) range.

```
db.auditLog.distinct( {"data.userName"}, {ts: /.*05/19/2016*./ )
```

from

```
_id: ObjectId("51d33bc8e4b09d71ea4c45d4")
ts: 07/02/2013 04:44:56 PM (-0400)
data:
    userName: "adminuser"
```

This ain't it but you probably know what I am trying to do.

I would also like to use $gte and $lt if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your syntax is almost right. The first parameter to [`distinct()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/) takes a field name (string), though, not a document.

```
db.auditLog.distinct( "data.userName", {ts: /.*05/19/2016*./} )
```

This is based on the assumption that your `ts` field is a string. Otherwise querying it with a regex wouldn't make sense...

Comment: I did try that in the form of db.auditLog.distinct( "data.userName", {ts: /.*2016*./} ) and even tried 2013 , 2017, etc which I know are there but its returning [ ] . Even /.*19*./ doesn't return anything. using distinct with only data.userName returns several userNames. Perhaps ts is not a string?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, ts was a date, sorry for the lack of clarification and thanks for getting me closer to where I could work it out.

```
db.auditLog.distinct( "data.userName", {ts: { $gte : new ISODate("2017-01-01") }} )
```

this works.